# The first number of terms of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The task is to list the first 10 terms of the sequence whose $n$th term is $n!-2^n$. Easy enough, except to me there's some ambiguity regarding the initial term. I happened to start at $n=0$ because the general term is defined for $n=0$. Thus my initial term is 0. But the book's initial term is $-1$, meaning it started at $n=1$. How do you know whether to start at $n=1$ or $n=0$? Is the fact that they asked for the *first* 10 terms indicate that you start $n$ at 1? Like if they said, "list the zeroth 10 terms," then you start $n$ at $0$? Or is it just "convention" to start at $n=1$ unless otherwise noted?

Edit: Webster's Dictionary defines "first" as "coming before all others in time, order, or importance." I don't know if the English meaning translates to math, but if it did, "first" is synonymous with "initial." So "first 10 terms" could be read, "initial 10 terms." In which case, the first term of this sequence could be $0$ or $-1$, depending on how the sequence is indexed. In that case there would be ambiguity, unless there was an understood convention regarding indexing.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $0!-2^0=1-1=0$.

Comment: @Nishant: Thanks; that’s what I get for posting before I’m awake.

Answer (score 5):

If the $\color{red}n$th term is $\color{red}n!-2^{\color{red}n}$, then the $\color{red}1$st term is $\color{red}1!-2^{\color{red}1}$.

The (one) first term is the first term; the two first terms are the first and the second term, ...

This may not make set theorista happy (or at least make them disagree), but we need to translate a linguistic expression here.

Comment: No. The first term depends on what the first allowable value of $n$ is.

Comment: Point taken, but the issue is the phrase "the first 10 terms," not "the first term". So, does "first 10 terms" necessarily imply that the initial term is indexed to 1?

Comment: @yroc: Not to me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "first" is what you obtain by substituting $1$ for $n$ in "$n$th". If thay had written $a_n=n!-2^n$ instead of "$n$th term", I agree that the 0-or-1 ambiguity would strike.

Comment: @Hagen: No, ‘first’ is *not* necessarily what you obtain by substituting $1$ for $n$. It depends entirely on where the indexing starts. ‘First’ is not synonymous with ‘one-th’.

Comment: @Brian Then do you count first, second, third, threeth, fourth, fifth?

Comment: Unfortunately, your translation is not necessarily correct, and your translation may differ from that intended by the author of any given book or question. Your answer does readers a disservice, and if I believed in downvoting, I would do so.

Comment: @Hagen: I fail to see the relevance of your question to the issue at hand.

Comment: The natural languae ordinal numberals are (apart from the first few) of the form $n$th where $n$ is the standard numeral (such as *seventeenth* corresponding to *seventeen*). In this way the words *first* and  *second* are only a special case that would systematically be *oneth* and *twoth*. Hence if I know that the $n$th thing is $f(n)$, this means that the first thing is $f(1)$. If my sequences run $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$, then the first term is $a_0$ - but the $n$th term is $a_{n-1}$, the term at index $n-1$. Even worse, if I have $\ldots, a_{-1},a_0,a_1,\ldots$, there is no first term.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether ‘$n$-th’ is to be interpreted as an ordinal word like ‘first’ and ‘third’, or whether it’s to be interpreted as ‘having index $n$’, **and both interpretations are found**. Enough. I’ve made my point, and readers can do what they please.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I wish I knew what to do! Alas, I think I'm more confused now than when I asked the question! (notwithstanding your commendable efforts :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention to start at $n=1$. Unfortunately, they should be more explicit. For example, a sequence is usually defined as

$$(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$$

where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers. Typically that does not include $0$ and when one wants to express the set of non-negative integers (i.e. including zero) one denotes it $\mathbb{N}_0$. Though this notation is not universal and most books should be more explicit about it.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that $\Bbb N$ typically does not include $0$. In the mathematical circles with which I’m most familiar it typically *does* include $0$, and if you want to exclude $0$, you write $\Bbb Z^+$ or the like. Both conventions are quite widespread. Set theorists in particular are likely to assume that sequences start at index $0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I try to avoid the ambiguity and use $\mathbb{Z}$ and the like when possible. I've seen some odd ones before. In Belgium apparently $\mathbb{N}_0$ means $0$ is excluded according to a colleague. Even weirder I've seen $\mathbb{N}_0$ as the empty set. My area is very applied (mathematical physics) and I was taught this way. A google search for the LaTeX code of mathbb{N}_0 returns a few people agreeing with me. Sorry if that's not representative.

Comment: Yes, I’ve seen that first usage of $\Bbb N_0$. I’ve never seen it used for the empty set, though; that’s just weird!

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter, so long as you are consistent about what the first, second, ... $n^\text{th}$, ... tenth, term means.

If you use start-one-indexing, then you wish to find the series $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9, a_{10}\}$ for which you know the $n^\text{th}$ term ($a_{n}$) is equal to $n!-2^n$.

If you use start-zero-indexing, then you wish to find the series $\{a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9\}$ for which you know the $n^\text{th}$ term ($a_{n-1}$) is equal to $n!-2^n$.

Proceed.

Comment: So you're saying that the initial term is always called the "first term", even if the sequence is start-zero indexed?